# c3p0 error : Last acquisition attempt exception: > java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, c3p0

Getting this exception in Tomcat server while using c3p0 :

Followed this link : http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/

But no success.

`....
Failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception:  > java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
...`

whereas if I remove connection pooling using c3p0 then every thing works fine.

Request, if anybody can give the detail step to configure c3p0 in Tomcat?

Comment: here's a recent one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363982/using-c3p0-with-tomcat-8-datasource you have to make sure that the JDBC driver class is visible within the classloader loading c3p0. (tomcat uses multiple classloaders.) also, if you are not, be sure to correctly configure c3p0's [driverClass](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#driverClass) property.

Comment: Did it get resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. This issue occurs because of C3p0 not able to set driverClass name while creating the datasource using c3p0.

You have to set it manually in application.
Ex: 
ComboPooledDataSource ds = (ComboPooledDataSource) DataSource;
ds.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

You can refer to this sample project. 
the reference code is present in SpringBootWithC3P0PoolingConfiguration.java.

https://github.com/ROBINSINGH0210/SpringBootWithC3P0Pooling.git